# How to open location services in settings programatically in UWP?

Tags: c#, uwp

I am currently working on a project where the user's current location to be saved each time the user logs in the app. If the location services are not on then I should be able to open location services in the settings. [image: Location]Can someone plz help me

Comment: If you mean "turn on/off the location service", the answer is you cann't do that programmatically. It has to be turned on/off by the user, and it has to be done manually. If you mean "go to the Location page in Settings", then check the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code opens location settings programmatically

```
<TextBlock x:Name="LocationDisabledMessage"  FontStyle="Italic"
             Visibility="Visible" Margin="0,15,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" >
      <Run Text="This app is not able to access Location. Go to " />
          <Hyperlink NavigateUri="ms-settings:privacy-location">
              <Run Text="Settings" />
          </Hyperlink>
      <Run Text=" to check the location privacy settings."/>
    </TextBlock>
```

For more details to [Get user's location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/get-location) check here

Comment: Is there a doc where all the UWP URI schema are defined?   Because the Microsoft Docs are a little bit unprecise about this argument...

Comment: @LucaLindholm Not sure what you mean "all the UWP URI schema are defined". Any app can define a URI schema. The ms-settings schema is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/launch-settings-app).

Comment: @RaymondChen   Exactly what I was looking for.   Thanks.